# Reading JSON value fails

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to understand some legacy production code.

Here's a test that simulates what the production code does:

```
Map json = new HashMap();
    json.put("messageCategory", "Hello World");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String out = mapper.writeValueAsString(json);

    System.out.println(out);

    final JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(out);

    Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", node.findValue("messageCategory"));
```

the output is:

```
{"messageCategory":"Hello World"}
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :Hello World
Actual   :null
```

The valueToTree methods returns null and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's null because you are serializing a string in your valueToTree() call. So, after the mapping your node contains a single String of this form:

```
"{\"messageCategory\":\"Hello World\"}"
```

And so your node contains no property named 'messageCategory'.

Change

```
final JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(out);
```

to

```
final JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(json);
```